# How to update mongodb schema after created the model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a node.js app uses express and mongoose,

I have created my model as below

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = Lead;
```

and i am trying to add a new field here, so the schema objects looks like this

```
{
    name: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    mynewfield: {type: String }
  },
```

but when I create a new record as follows it doesn't write this new field into my database,

```
const newUser = new User({
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@email.com',
    mynewfield: 'some value'
});
```

new record looks like this

```
{
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@email.com',
}
```

I have tried update updateMany but this is only updating the existing records it doesn't work when creating a new record.

What is the best way to add this new field into my schema so when i create a new entry it will be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `{ strict: false }` to add new field in schema. Check the doc:  [strict](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)

```
const thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });
const thing = new Thing({ iAmNotInTheSchema: true });
thing.save(); // iAmNotInTheSchema is now saved to the db!!
```